# Nextjs 9.3 tailwindcss + antd build missing css

Tags: next.js, antd, tailwind-css

I'm following these 2 examples to setup a Nextjs + Tailwindcss + Antd project:

- [nextjs-with-antd](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design)
- [nextjs-with-tailwindcss](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss)

I'm able to `yarn dev` with no issue, but when I tried to `yarn build` and `yarn start` the project, antd's css is missing.

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/itsmetambui/next-with-tailwindcss-antd) to reproduce the issue.

**Edit:**
I found out that when I remove the purge css plugin in `postcss.config.js` the issue is resolved. So the issue is purge css purged all external css files when `yarn build`. How should I update the postcss config?

**Edit 2:**
Trying to ignore purging for external files didn't work:

```
/* purgecss start ignore */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
/* purgecss end ignore */
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Nextjs + antd. I resolved the issue by changing configuration in `postcss.config.js`, i mentioned specific selector for `ant` classes using regular expression in `safelist` to select class names starting with `ant`.

`/ant.*/` is the expression I used, and the rest of the config is from [docs](https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html).

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: "no-2009",
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          "custom-properties": false,
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        content: [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./containers/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./features/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./common/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        ],
        defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: ["html", "body", /ant.*/],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```